# Fill up array of a Javascript-File by using other file

Tags: javascript, arrays, call

I have a js-file(A) including an array

```
$(function(){
    function initVMap(){
        $('#vmap').vectorMap({
            map: 'world_mill',


     //...........................
            markers: [
                {latLng: [3.2, 73.22], name: 'Maldives'},
                {latLng: [35.88, 14.5], name: 'Malta'},
                {latLng: [12.05, -61.75], name: 'Grenada'},
                {latLng: [13.16, -59.55], name: 'Barbados'},
                {latLng: [17.11, -61.85], name: 'Antigua and Barbuda'},
                {latLng: [-4.61, 55.45], name: 'Seychelles'},
                {latLng: [7.35, 134.46], name: 'Palau'},                        
            ]
        });
    }

   //........................
```

the array data will be provided by another system and changes constantly. So, the idea is to provide array-data out of the other json-file(B). My question is. Could somebody tell me if and how to call the other file(B) to fill up the array of my json-file(A)?

Comment: Are you trying to do this in the browser or on the server? How are you accessing file B? Where is it?

Comment: I hopefully try to do this in the browser. File(A) & File(B) are on the same server in the same directory.